# Strange hard shutdown in Windows 7 x64 with nForce 570 Ultra + Radeon

Tags: windows, ubuntu, shutdown, amd-radeon, nvidia-nforce

i have a strange problem with Windows 7 x64 making a hard shutdown after some minutes of playing games (or any videocard intensive program).

My machine is:

1. AMD Athlon X2 5400+ - 2,8Ghz
2. 3,5 GB of memory
3. AMD Radeon R7950 (i know... the processor it's old for the videocard)
4. Motherboard MSI K9N Platinum v1.1
5. PSU Thermaltake Smart Series 530W
6. Windows 7 x64 (activated)

What i tried:

1. Update BIOS to latest version.
2. Update drivers to latest version.
3. Check that my motherboard version doesn´t suffer the nforce shutdown problem.
4. Inspect the Windows event registry searching for ACPI shutdown.
5. Check **FurMark**, **Cities in Motion 2** and **The Witcher 2** in Linux Ubuntu 14 x64, and this is where the **most strangest** happens. The machine doesn´t shutdow. So i discard a hardware problem.

This machine was in use many years with a Geforce 8800GT and does't suffer this problem (Windows XP).

Can anyone help me with this problem?
I Don´t what can i try (i can´t afford another mother + micro + memory now)

Thanks in advance (sorry my english)

**Edit**: add some facts
 1. The machine is clean (i build it again after some months, with new case and hard disk, clean the motherboard, change the thermal paste, check for inflated capacitors, etc.)
 2. If i put a stand fan, the machine doesn´t shutdown, so it´s a problem of temperatures, taht doesn´t happen in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is more related to temperature rather than a driver or BIOS issue. After some time, the thermal compound gets old and transfers the heat to the heat sink less efficiently, causing the temperature of the core to raise. If you have the right knowledge I suggest this:

1. Clean your computer thoroughly. Use compressed, canned air (I don't know how it's called in english).
2. Replace the thermal compound of your processor. Make sure you only apply the necessary amount and nothing more. If it spills to the sides, it'll isolate the heat instead and it could be worse.
3. Make sure your computer is in a well ventilated area.

Since you didn't mention when was the last time you cleaned your system, I assumed those *years* passed without doing the proper maintenance.

Update:

I also remember that my Ubuntu installation on my laptop was kind of more *tolerant* to temperature: windows would shut down almost immediately  while Ubuntu lasted some more minutes, but my notebook's state was far more critical back then.

Comment: Ariel, gracias por tu respuesta, lo voy a volver a limpiar al microprocesador.
--------
Ariel, thanks for your answer, i will clean again the microprocessor.

Comment: I clean the processor and heatsink, put new thermal paste, but the problem persist

Comment: Does it happen exactly at the same moment, or by doing a very specific  thing? If it shuts down, and you turn it on right away, does it last less time before it turns off again? Does it last less time every time you turn it on?

Comment: It doesn´t happend at any specific moment, just some minutes while playing. If i turning on inmediatly, it takes the same time to turn it off again. Now i try with a Athlon X2 3600+ and doesn´t turn off. Gonna try a few things with the 5400+